# Cannot Resolve symbol "List" and many other keywords in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm very new to android studio and this is my first day :), this is my main.java

```
package com.example.myapplication1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.text.html.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    String[] items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listViewSong);

        runtimePermission();


    }

    public void runtimePermission()
    {
        Dexter.withContext(this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                        displaySongs();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
    }
    public ArrayList<File> findSong (File file)
    {
        ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        File[] files = file.listFiles();

        for(File singleFile: files)
        {
            if(singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden())
            {
                arrayList.addAll((findSong(singleFile)));
            }
            else
            {
                if(singlefile.getName().endswith(".mp3") || singlefile.getName().endswith(".wav"))
                {
                    arrayList.add(singleFile);
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayList;
    }

    void displaySongs()
    {
        final ArrayList<File> mySongs = findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

        items = new String[mySongs.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<mySongs.size();i++)
        {
            items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().toString.replace(target:'.mp3', replacement:"").replace(target:'.wav', replacement:"");

        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(contex:this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        listView.setAdapter((myAdapter));
    }
}
```

I get errors such as
Cannot Resolve symbol "List", listView, Environment.
What can I do, I think it's got something to do with java installation or dependencies.
And when I run the code I get, Gradle build failed in 1 s 157 ms

Comment: Make sure you installed the required JDK and also don't forget to configure it in your Android Studio, Go to Project Structure -> SDK location and verify it.

Comment: I do have JDK installed which I use on a regular basis, and I've configured it in my Android studio as well

Answer (score 0):

Check in xml whether android:id="@+id/list" instead of android:id="@android:id/list" is entered by mistake

Comment: The compiler cannot find the JDK's classes. I doubt that this is an issue with the xml file.

Comment: There's nothing like android:id="@+id/list

Comment: Yes, even I feel compiler cannot find JDK classes, what can I do to fix it